# Best Practice append, Insert into Table . Queries

Tags: sql, delphi, ado

Hi trying to acknowledge the best practice to update Insert data from A table A to Table B . I have ADOConnection1 Table Clientes and ADOConnection2 Table Q_Clientes Now i knead to update

```
ADOConnection1 Table Clientes \Q_Clientes has the same similar to Clientes only it´s in another Locacion i can call clientes.FieldByName('Localização').text := Q_Clientes.FieldByName('Localização').text; .......................................... .......................................... ..........................................
```

or is there a simple Way to update Table Clientes .

Thank´s

Answer (score 1):

you can do that in a query:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 
(SELECT * FROM TABLE2 T2 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE1 T1 on T2.IDField = T1.IDField 
WHERE T1.SomeOtherField is null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what database you connect, you can something like 
UPDATE..FROM (SQL Server) or use a SP for that.